# How can I associate "foreign key" ids of one index to the corresponding data of another index in Elasticsearch using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

**Situation**

Elasticsearch has indices "users" and "calls," where users can dial or receive many calls. On the database end, the calls table has user ids that act as foreign keys from the users table. This relationship in Elasticsearch directly correlates to the DBs design.

Here is an example Elasticsearch JSON output using Sense:

> GET /calls/call/23

```
{
"_index": "calls",
"_type": "call",
"_id": "23",
"_version": 2,
"found": true,
  "_source": {
    "id": 23,
    "user1_id": 1, //Jack "called"
    "user2_id": 12, // George "received"
    "start_time": "2015-05-29T16:01:28.233Z",
    "end_time": null,
    "status": "NONE",
    "reason": null,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
  }
}
```

This is a rails app, so my issue is when I search for calls by name in the calls view, nothing is found because only the ids (user1_id and user2_id) are stored in the calls index. I essentially need Elasticsearch to return results if searching by names for calls similar to this DB query:

```
select calls.id AS "Call id", users.id AS "User Id", users.name AS "Name" from calls, users where (calls.user1_id=users.id OR calls.user2_id=users.id) AND users.name LIKE '%Jack%';
```

The above query of course returns all calls made and received by the name searched for, Jack, while comparing the user and call ids.

**Desired output**

```
{
"_index": "calls",
"_type": "call",
"_id": "23",
"_version": 2,
"found": true,
  "_source": {
    "id": 23,
    "dialer": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Jack"
    },
    "receiver": {
      "id": 12,
      "name": "George"
    },
    "start_time": "2015-04-27T17:29:04.868Z",
    "end_time": "2015-04-27T17:29:59.198Z",
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "reason": "User hungup",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
  }
}
```

From what I've gathered when looking into creating new mappings or creating custom search queries in Elasticsearch, I had figured I needed to create the calls index with new source mappings "user1_name" and "user2_name"; then figured Elasticsearch would populate those source mappings accordingly, associating user1_id and user2_id with their names in the corresponding user index.

**What I've tried**

I tried a HTTP requests in Sense, which manually creates my desired tree structure, but only for one call item:

```
PUT /calls/call/23
{
"id": 23,
"dialer": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Jack"
},
"receiver": {
    "id": 12,
    "name": "George"
},
"start_time": "2015-04-27T17:29:04.868Z",
"end_time": "2015-04-27T17:29:59.198Z",
"status": "SUCCESS",
"reason": "User hungup",
"created_at": null,
"updated_at": null
}
```

I also tried creating aliases in hopes of combining the indices for relationships:

```
POST /_aliases
{
"actions" : [
    { "add" : { "index" : "users", "alias" : "searchcalls" } },
    { "add" : { "index" : "calls", "alias" : "searchcalls" } }
  ]
}
```

Also, there's this: http://www.spacevatican.org/2012/6/3/fun-with-elasticsearch-s-children-and-nested-documents/

But there's no way I can be expected to do these things for tens of thousands potentially millions of calls...

**Question**

Any direction on how to modify Elasticsearch or my rails code would be much appreciated. I am 100% stuck in the mud here. Not sure if I need to create mappings, do something with ES, or do something else entirely in rails or HOW to do any of it... Simply put, how can I associate user ids in the calls index with the user names that exists in the users index in order that I can have the ability to search for calls by name? I imagine whatever indexing method is required will need to be handled in bulk and stay in sync with the live DB... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After just hammering things out for the past week, I believe I found a solution. After piecing together the massive Elasticsearch doc on [Bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) and [Rubydocs](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/elasticsearch-api/Elasticsearch/API/Actions#bulk-instance_method), this is what I came up with in rails:

**Model**

```
# elasticsearch custom mapping
mappings :dynamic => 'true' do
  indexes :dialer do 
    indexes :id, :type => 'long'
    indexes :name, :type => 'string'
    indexes :email, :type => 'string'
  end
  indexes :receiver do 
    indexes :id, :type => 'long'
    indexes :name, :type => 'string'
    indexes :email, :type => 'string'
  end
end

# customize the index for for relationships
def as_indexed_json(options={})
  as_json(
    except: [:user1_id, :user2_id],
    include: {
      dialer: { only: [:id, :name, :email]},
      receiver: { only: [:id, :name, :email]}
    }
  )
end
```

This gives me my desired output, but the problem I am facing now is the import is slow as molasses...

[This post](http://www.codinginthecrease.com/news_article/show/409843?referrer_id=948927) was helpful, especially the "write a faster import" section, but still slow as molasses. Any comments would still be helpful, thanks. I am open to any and all suggestions!